# Regex to allow for 1-500 characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

```
# A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _ in the middle but never starting or ending in a _
# At least 5, no more than 500 characters

/[A-Za-z\d][-A-Za-z\d]{3,498}[A-Za-z\d]/ }
```

Hello I have the following above. I want to update the rules to allow for 1 character. I tried changing 3 to 1.

```
    /[A-Za-z\d][-A-Za-z\d]{1,498}[A-Za-z\d]/ }
```

But this fails.

How can I allow for at minimum 1 character that is A-Z, a-z, or 0-9 but not a dash and maintain the rules listed above?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match a single alphanumeric character, and optionally match between 0 and 498 alphanumeric chars including a dash, followed by a single alphanumeric character.

```
/[A-Za-z\d]([-A-Za-z\d]{,498}[A-Za-z\d])?/
```

Updated to allow `_` in the middle part as well:

```
/[A-Za-z\d]([-\w]{,498}[A-Za-z\d])?/
```

Also, depending on your use case, you might have to surround your regex with `\A` and `\Z` which mark the beginning and end of a string, or word boundaries (`\b`). This would be necessary if you are using this to match (validate) input strings, for example.

Note that if you use Ruby 1.8.7, you have to use `{0,498}` instead of `{,498}`.

Update to finally settle this, based on your other question, you **have to add the anchors**:

```
/\A[A-Za-z\d]([-\w]{,498}[A-Za-z\d])?\Z/
```

Comment: @AnApprentice, do you want to allow it only in the middle? Then simply add `_` to the middle group between `[]`. Or replace it with `[-\w]`, because `\w` equals `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: Yes just the middle please. Like Twitter

Comment: @molf, updated the question. Would it be possible to edit your answer with the update so get it right? Thanks

Comment: @Aillyn - I'm not sure why you say that. This works just fine. For both this one and mine, if you're using an online regex tester, try changing `{,498}` with `{0,498}` and you'll see that it works just fine... that just has to do with the flavor of regex parser. See here: http://rubular.com/r/cRTMLldmat

Comment: The use of `\b` or `\A` or `\Z` (or `^` or `$`) aren't optional. The requirements say **"no more than 500 characters"**, and that means you have to guard against > 500 characters. This pattern straight-up doesn't do that. It also doesn't enforce the requirement of `[A-Za-z\d]` at the beginning and end, because it will match `a-b` in `-a-b-`.

Comment: @Justin, I have to disagree slightly. If the regexp is used as (for example) `string.sub(REGEXP, "foo")`, the part replaced will perfectly stop at 500 characters and ignore surrounding dashes. As I mentioned in the answer, if the regexp is used to **validate** input, then the boundaries are necessary. I can't tell the use case from the question.

Comment: I have to admit, you have a point there. I couldn't think of a plausible use case for a non-anchored version, but the substitution idea is at least possible. Definitely looks like validation to me, but I see your point.

Answer (score 9):

You can simplify things by using lookaheads to encode each of your rules separately:

```
/^(?!_)(?!.*_$)\w{1,500}$/
```

Explanation:

- `(?!_)`: Doesn't start with an underscore.
- `(?!.*_$)`: Doesn't end with an underscore.
- `[\w]{1,500}`: Contains between 1 to 500 allowed characters.

One advantage is that the minimum and maximum limits (1 and 500) are made very explicit and are easy to change. It's also easy to add some types of new restrictions later without changing the existing code - just add another lookahead that checks that rule.

Here's an example of it working online (changed to 1 to 10 allowed characters instead of 1 to 500, for clarity):

- [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/jT5nkgpakn)

Comment: I like this one the best. I don't know if Ruby supports the `/x` regex modifier that allows whitespace and commenting, but if it does, and you comment the regex accordingly, it's actually quite clear.

Comment: @Aillyn: I'd argue that it *is* simpler - *if* you know what lookaheads are (and yes, I'm aware that not everyone does, but I'd say they're worth learning). I think it's simpler because each rule is encoded seperately. It's easy to modify one of the rules without affecting the others. Also there is less repetition in the regular expression. This also happens to make it more concise in this case.

Comment: I agree that this is simplest, and would definitely consider it the easiest to read and understand. +1.

Comment: @CanSpice, it does, at least with Oniguruma/on 1.9 (any recent one).

Comment: Like your use of lookarounds, but be aware this opens a pathological performance issue when the matched string is very long. The negative lookahead will continue to match until the end of the string. This is possibly only important if the regexp is used to match a part inside a larger string (in which case the anchors wouldn't be justified though).

Comment: @molf: Yeah, shame Ruby hasn't got support for lookbehinds `(?<!-)$` (at least not the last time I checked).

Comment: Since the OP says he wants to allow `_` in the middle instead of `-`, and since [Ruby treats `\w` as ASCII-only](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), you could rewrite this as `/^(?!_)\w{0,499}(?!_)\w$/` and fix the performance issue @molf noticed. This loses some of the elegance, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[A-Za-z\d]([-A-Za-z\d]{0,498}[A-Za-z\d])?$/
```

1. Make the whole second part optional (with the parenthesis ending with a `?`)
2. Within the second part, make the middle part optional (using the `{0,<number>}` construct, which doesn't specify a lower limit)

Comment: @Aillyn - which part of this is incorrect? In fact, this is identical to [molf's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680437/regex-to-allow-for-1-500-characters/7680472#7680472) answer above, and was posted first.

Comment: @Aillyn - That has to be the most pedantic downvote I've received, particularly in light of the fact that the expression itself is correct. *shrug* to each their own.

Comment: @eykanal: But if you leave off the anchors, the string `-abcd` matches when it shouldn't. Therefore without the anchors your answer is wrong and is deserving of a downvote. (I didn't downvote, by the way)

Comment: @CanSpice - If the string `-abcd` was used, it would only match the `abcd` part of the string, not the `-`. The OP didn't specify anchors, so I didn't add them.

Comment: @eykanal - How is it pedantic? Either it works or it doesn't. I might have given you a warning before downvoting since it's such an easy mistake, but Aillyn had a point.

Comment: @JustinMorgan - see my comment to CanSpice above. The OP didn't specify anchors, so I didn't specify anchors. Maybe he wants to capture substrings of a larger string, who knows? I'm answering what he posted.

Comment: But he did say "At least 5, no more than 500 characters".